# How to query data from sqlite3 database and put them into HTML elements using node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, database, sqlite

i'm trying to query data from sqlite database with node.js everything goes smoothly  when i run it and print the output to the console but i want to put the output data from the database into HTML elements like p element but this is not working for me !!

this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="para"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var fullname;
        var fname = "bishoy";
        const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
        let db = new sqlite3.Database('./test.db');
        let sql = `SELECT Id,
                        Name,
                         Age,
                   BloodGroup
                   FROM donor
               WHERE Name = ?
              ORDER BY Name`;

        db.each(sql, [fname], (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
            throw err;
            }
       fullname = (`${row.Name}`);
       callback(fullname)
      });

      function callback(fullname){
          document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = fullname
      }


      db.close()

</script>
```